# Is there a efficient way to prepend a list from items from another list?

Tags: python, list, vectorization, prepend

Given two list, the goal is to append the items from the 2nd list to the 1st and return the matrix of lists, e.g.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [123, 456]  # m no. of items

def func(x, y):
  return [[i] + x for i in y]

func(x, y)
```

[out]:

```
[[123, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [456, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

**While this works for small no. of items in y, having O(m) is kind of expensive. Is there an efficient way to optimize this prepending? Or O(m) is the best possible?**

Comment: I don't think there is a more efficient way to do it (I might be wrong though). However, if you aren't constantly accessing elements of the list and only intend to use them once, you could use a generator: `([i]+x for i in y)`. That way it only yields one value of the list at a time, making it O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: If you actually want lists, you won't be able to do any better than that. If you're happy with lazy containers, you could wrap this up in a class with a custom `__getitem__` which is indexable on demand.

Comment: Not if you use lists.

Comment: What do you mean with "matrix", and how do you imagine producing m lists in less than O(m)? Even if you do something like what @wim said, you pay O(1) at creation of the "matrix" but O(m) during its usage (unless you don't use it all, but then that should be stated on the question).

Comment: Actually this is such an odd question that I wonder whether you're asking the right question. Do you really care about the complexity class, or do you just want it faster? And how much faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to produce an output with **m** different values O(m) is the best you can do.  In this case, you'll also be processing the **n** values of x **m** times so it's going to end up O(mn).

Assuming that Python's internal `copy()` method is faster than a concatenation plus a list creation, you could setup a template list and make a copy at each iteration witht the first item populated from the other list:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [123, 456]

def func(x, y):
    template = [0]+x
    return  [template.copy() for template[0] in y]

print(func(x,y))
[[123, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [456, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: using `template[0]` as the target list is really confusing. This is a highly obfuscated way of doing something for very small practical gains (assuming they even exist)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's not confusing or obfuscated at all, it's straightforward, directly does what we want, an excellent use case for that feature.